# How to remove the white spaces down the html page while using angular 6?

Tags: html, css, angular6

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDwgO.png) This is my common style.css file:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100% !important;
}
```

But still whitespaces are coming at the bottom of every page. I have tried giving margin:0, padding: 0 too. It doesnt work. Can someone please tell me how to remove the whitespace.

Comment: White space after the `footer`? Share a screenshot if possible

Comment: Can you please provide more info? Such as the source code of your footer HTML so we can figure out why it happens.

Comment: @EliyaCohen Actually Im not using footer tags.

Comment: @Priyanka I meant the bottom of your page. Do you have a demo?

Comment: @EliyaCohen I have attached the screenshot of the image. Blue color is the whitespace which im getting in the page. could you please check that?

Comment: @Priyanka I need you to post your CSS and HTML. Otherwise I can't help you

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Try This code

```css
*{
   margin:0px;
   padding:0px
}
body{
  margin-bottom:0px;
  padding-bottom:0px
}
```

***Try Below Things***

**remove tag**

remove break tags after last elemnts

**Other**

remove margin-bottom of last elemts

Comment: can you share screenshot

Comment: I have attached the screenshot. can you pls chck now in question? @Hariom Singh

Comment: still I'm getting the same error. @Hariom Singh There is no br tag & margin bottom also .

Comment: go to page than open developer tools. after that select white space